# Cannot get Barba JS transition to work on page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap, barbajs

I'm trying to get [Barba JS](https://barba.js.org/), alongside [GSAP](https://greensock.com/), implemented on my `React` website.

For reference, I have followed this [video tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ergc889Jghc&ab_channel=Codegrid), this tutorial of course, is not in `React`.

**Here is my folder structure** which showcases all of the relevant files for this transition effect:

```html
theme
  public
    index.html
  src
    components
      Header
        Header.js
    pages
      Homepage
      Contact
    utils
      anim.js
      helpers.js
  App.js
  index.js
```

**I have the following packages installed:**

- [gsap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsap) - version `3.8.0`
- [@barba/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@barba/core) - version `2.9.7`

**Current results**

- No console errors and no compilation errors.
- When switching pages, there's no transition. It almost feels like `barba` isn't initiated.

**Demo:**

As the demo involves a few files, I have created a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/barba-transition-test-2sdpj?file=/src/index.js).

**Edit:**

Have updated my `barba` transition code and have added `debug: true`. Then, when hovering over my contact page button, the console shows the error: `[@barba/core]  Error: Fetch error at XMLHttpRequest.o.onerror`?

```js
import { pageTransition } from "./helpers";
import barba from '@barba/core';

export function delay(n) {
  n = n || 2000;
  return new Promise((done) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      done();
    }, n);
  });
}

barba.init({
  debug: true,
  sync: true,
  transitions: [
    {
      async leave(data){
        const done = this.async();
        pageTransition();
        await delay(1000);
        done();
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have since concluded that Barba JS is not compatible with React. Seems like the library needs updating to work with `React Router`.

[More details here](https://github.com/barbajs/barba/issues/221)

Answer (score 3):

Dificult to say but you can set debug: true, inside the initialization of barba so it will spit out logs of whats happening ;)

barba.init({
debug: true,
sync: false,
//views das paginas
views: [{.....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).